# Bold effect not applied in Helvetica font if using chromium but works in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, fonts

This simple body here: `<b style=" font-family: Helvetica;">aaa</b>`
Shown here:

```html
    <b style=" font-family: Helvetica;">aaa</b>
```

Renders differently, in my chromium it doesn't gets bold, but in my firefox it stays bold.
I'm at ubuntu and my chromium is version 88.0.4324.96 snap 64 bits and my firefox is 84.0.2 (64-bits).
Since I found this while doing web dev work, I'll tag it to that.

Comment: And does it look fine here that I made it runnable? Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

change the default font  setting of your chromium browser to helvatica
it should work fine

Comment: In that case , Then you need to install Helvetica Font  (.ttf extension for windows ) and  selecting  it in chromium 
moreover you need to give correct name of font in your code as it is installed in your system

Comment: Yup, it's already installed, checked that already, should've included that information in the question.